# Prove that $\text{range}$ $(T^{k})$ $=$ $\text{range}$ $(T^m)$ for all $k$ $>$ $m$ if $\text{range}$ $(T^{m})=$ $\text{range}$ $(T^{m+1})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Does the assumption imply $\text{range}(T^{m+1})=\text{range}(T^{(m+1)+1})?$ Continuing on this fashion and letting  $k=m + 1$ , where $n$ is a positive integer we have to eventually get to $\text{range}(T^{k-1})=\text{range}(T^{k})$ and then, conclude by the chain of equalities $\text{range}(T^{m})=\text{range}(T^{k})$?

Is this train of thought correct, is induction more appropriate or is the dimensional approach the only viable one?

Here is a suggested solution (based on the fundamental theorem of linear maps)

Exercise 17:

https://linearalgebras.com/8a.html

Comment: Have you tried to prove the result $\text{range}(T^{m+1})=\text{range}(T^{(m+1)+1})?
$? What are your issues to do so?

Comment: You are right, induction is the best way here since this theorem holds even in an infinite-dimensional space.